# Array Splice - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

Its a very small issue and for the life of me I can't figure out what it is. My brain has locked itself from thinking. I need someone else to have a look this code.

The output of the code should be: `[1,0,0,0]`

**UPDATE:**

*The function should be able to read an array of numbers and if it finds any zeros within the array it should move them to the end of the array.*

The output of the code keeps coming as: `[0,1,0,0]`

```
var arrNum = [0,0,0,1];

function test() {
   for(var i=0; i<arrNum.length; i++){

 if(arrNum[i] == 0){

    arrNum.splice(i,1)
    arrNum.splice(arrNum.length, 1, 0)

    }
 }
 return alert(arrNum)
}
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vFEr263YhsZuFhPRBpkQ?p=preview) is a working plunker.

Apologies for this, I know the issue is something very small but my brain has stopped working now and I need a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: I get [0,0,0,1] when ran in the console

Comment: @AdamJeffers thank you for the reply. Did you try the plunker. It doesn't work on alert. Again thanks

Comment: If you are trying to reverse the array try arrNum.reverse()

Comment: 1 min mate not yet...

Comment: you problem in condition :-)

Comment: "The output of the code should be: [1,0,0,0]" ... why is that? What it's purpose?

Comment: @AdamJeffers see update

Comment: Ah in that case, see my answer...

Comment: No answer actually explained it, but your code isn't working because once you remove the `0` from given position, another number fits in there, but you don't check it (the `FOR` just increases the value of the `i` and checks next number, jumping one, in this case). If that new number for the given position is also a `0`, it's skipped. Add one more `0` to the beginning of the array and you'll see two `0`s wrong. @LorenzovonMatterhorn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the way you have it written, you need to loop in the reverse order. You end up skipping indexes when you remove the index. Looping in the reverse direction keeps you from skipping them.

```
for(var i=arrNum.length-1; i>=0; i--){
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, the result will be correct.

Comment: This solution works!! Not sure why the down vote though. Could you explain the logic behind your answer I want understand it. Thank you.

Comment: thanks you for the answer. I'll up vote and accept it!  Cheers again.

Comment: "The function should be able to read an array of numbers and if it finds any zeros within the array it should move them to the end of the array.". "Within" zeros will not ever be on the beginning.

Comment: @YuraYakym Nowhere does it say it is not the beginning. You are reading it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can use unshift() to insert at beginning of an array and push() to the end...

```
    var arrNum = [0,0,0,1];
    var output = [];

    function test() 
    {
       for(var i=0; i<arrNum.length; i++)
       {
         if(arrNum[i] == 0)
            output.push(0);
         else
            output.unshift(arrNum[i]);
     }
     return alert(output)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrNum = [0,0,0,1];
var result = [];

arrNum.forEach(function(v) {
    !!v ? result.unshift(v) : result.push(v);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating with index i = 0,1,2,3 and at the same time removing first elements of array. So your iteration can not see the 1, it jumps over as it is moved to already iterated index. Easiest would be to just reverse the loop to bypass the issue.

```
var arrNum = [0,0,0,1];

function test() {
  for(var i= arrNum.length; i >= 0; i--){

    if(arrNum[i] == 0){
      arrNum.splice(i,1)
      arrNum.splice(arrNum.length, 1, 0)
    }
  }
  return alert(arrNum)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Prefer built-in functions every time possible.

```
var output = [];
[0,0,0,1].forEach(function(num) {
  if(num == 0) output.push(0);
  else output.unshift(num)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a temporary array to help? The problem with your code is that the splice() function modifies the original array, and you are doing it inside the loop.

The code below produces what you need:

```
var arrNum = [0,0,0,1];
var arrResult = new Array();

function test() {

   for(var i=arrNum.length-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
        arrResult.push(arrNum[i]);
   }

   arrNum = arrResult;
   return alert(arrNum);
}
```

With another array to store the new values, you gain flexibility to do whatever you need with the data of the first array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: "The function should be able to read an array of numbers and if it finds any zeros within the array it should move them to the end of the array.". "Within" zeros will not ever be on the beginning.

Comment: You're welcome! Just to explain: I changed the loop to iterates backward the array, because you want to invert the positions of the elements. To accomplish this, you can just iterate backwards like I posted. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

A nice little way using Objects - busy learning them so just posting a variation of deligation

```
var methods = {
    moveZero: function(arr){
        //console.log(arr);
        var newArr = [];
        for(var i  = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] === 0){
                newArr.push(arr[i]);
            }else{
                newArr.unshift(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log(newArr);
    }
}

var arrNum = Object.create(methods);
arrNum.moveZero([0,0,50,56,85,0,0,43,10,0,1]);
```

---

**JSFiddle -** https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/qh0xztgc/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was you are modifying an array while looping over it in if statement.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9gv9SqSvxb9efP2F6lCy?p=preview) is a working plunker of your example.

```
var len = arrNum.length;
var index = 0;

while(len) {

    if(arrNum[index] == 0) {
        arrNum.splice(index,1);
        arrNum.push(0);
    } else {
        ++index;
    }

    --len;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the operation you want to do is actually sorting, for readability and compactness of code maybe you should be doing this instead:

```
var arrNum = [0,1,0,0]; 
arrNum.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a == 0 ? 1 : 0;
});
```

It can contain any number and will keep order of others than 0